# Prove a recursive function in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I have defined the following recursive function:

```
primrec span :: "('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list * 'a list" where
"span P [] = ([], [])"
| "span P (x#xs) = 
  (let (ys, zs) = span P xs in 
   if P x then (x#ys, zs) else (ys, x#zs))"
```

which splits a list into two sublists by a filter `p` and insert `x` in the middle.
Now I would like to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma invariant_length:
shows "length (fst (span P l)) + length (snd (span P l)) = length l"
```

I did the proof by induction

```
lemma invariant_length:
shows "length (fst (span P l)) + length (snd (span P l)) = length l"
proof (induction l)
case Nil
  then show ?case by auto
next
  case (Cons a l)
  show ?case
  proof(cases "P a")
    case True
    then have "span P (a # l) = (a # fst (span P l), snd (span P l))"
      by [where I stuck]
    then have "length (fst (span P (a # l))) + length (snd (span P (a # l))) 
               = length (a # fst (span P l)) + length(snd (span P l)) " 
      by simp
    then have "length (fst (span P (a # l))) + length (snd (span P (a # l))) 
               = Suc(length (fst (span P l))) + length(snd (span P l)) " 
      by simp
    with Cons have "length (fst (span P (a # l))) + length (snd (span P (a # l))) = Suc (length l)" 
      by simp
    then show ?thesis by simp
  next
    case False
        then have "span P (a # l) = (fst (span P l), a # snd (span P l))"
      by [where I stuck]
    then have "length (fst (span P (a # l))) + length (snd (span P (a # l))) 
               = length (fst (span P l)) + length(a # snd (span P l)) " 
      by simp
    then have "length (fst (span P (a # l))) + length (snd (span P (a # l))) 
               = length (fst (span P l)) + Suc(length(snd (span P l)))" 
      by simp
    with Cons have "length (fst (span P (a # l))) + length (snd (span P (a # l))) = Suc (length l)" 
      by simp
    then show ?thesis by simp
  qed
qed
```

I stuck at the first step of the two cases during the inductive step, where I have marked as `[where I stuck]`. I tried using `auto` or `simp` here but Isabelle says

```
Failed to finish proof⌂:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. P a ⟹ (case span P l of (ys, x) ⇒ (a # ys, x)) = (a # fst (span P l), snd (span P l))
```

How can I proceed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lemma invariant_length:
  "length (fst (span P l)) + length (snd (span P l)) = length l"
  by (induction l; simp add: prod.case_eq_if)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.